# Serialising Django object: how to output a clean list

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django app with a set of markets, connected through a foreign key to a price history, defined in `models.py` as follows:

```
class Market(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    current_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    description = models.TextField(default="")
    shares_yes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    shares_no = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    b = models.IntegerField(default=100)
    cost_function = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title[:50]

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('market_detail', args=[str(self.id)])

class Price(models.Model):
    market = models.ForeignKey(
        Market, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='prices', 
        default=None)
    price = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=5, 
        decimal_places=2, 
        default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.price)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('market_list')
```

In a template, users see the current market price and can buy or sell shares relating to that market. They should also see a price graph, which I'm trying to populate by serialising from `market.prices` into `price_items` as follows (from `views.py`, ignore the toy values in `labels`):

```
class ChartData(APIView):
   authentication_classes = []
   permission_classes = []

   def get(self, request, pk):
        market = Market.objects.get(pk=pk)
        price_items = serializers.serialize('json', market.prices.get_queryset(), fields=('price'))
        labels = [1, 2, 3, 4] # Toy labels
        data = {
            "labels": labels,
            "prices": price_items}
        return Response(data)
```

The relevant section of `urls.py` is as follows:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('list/', MarketListView.as_view(), name='market_list'),
    path('<int:pk>/', MarketDetailView.as_view(), name='market_detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/buy/', views.buy, name='buy'),
    path('<int:pk>/sell/', views.sell, name='sell'),
    # url(r'^api/chart/data/$', ChartData.as_view()),
    path('<int:pk>/api/chart/data/', ChartData.as_view(), name='chart_data'),

]
```

My problem is: **I can't figure out how to simply get a clean list of prices on the output side** to feed into a line chart at `data.prices` here:

```
<script>
        {% block jquery %}
            var endpoint = "{% url 'chart_data' market.id %}"
            var defaultData = []
            var labels = []
            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: endpoint,
                success: function(data){
                    labels = data.labels
                    defaultData = data.prices
                    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
                    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                        type: 'line',
                        data: {
                            labels: labels,
                            datasets : [{
                                label: 'Market price',
                                data: defaultData
                            }]
                        },
                        options: {
                            scales: {
                                yAxes: [{
                                    ticks: {
                                        suggestedMin: 0,
                                        suggestedMax: 1
                                    }
                                }]
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        {% endblock %}
</script>
```

Here's what I'm getting in json at the relevant `<int:pk>/api/chart/data/` url:

```
{"labels":[1,2,3,4],"prices":"[{\"model\": \"markets.price\", \"pk\": 4, \"fields\": {\"price\": \"0.90\"}}, {\"model\": \"markets.price\", \"pk\": 5, \"fields\": {\"price\": \"0.91\"}}, {\"model\": \"markets.price\", \"pk\": 6, \"fields\": {\"price\": \"0.92\"}}, {\"model\": \"markets.price\", \"pk\": 7, \"fields\": {\"price\": \"0.92\"}}, {\"model\": \"markets.price\", \"pk\": 8, \"fields\": {\"price\": \"0.93\"}}, {\"model\": \"markets.price\", \"pk\": 12, \"fields\": {\"price\": \"0.92\"}}, {\"model\": \"markets.price\", \"pk\": 13, \"fields\": {\"price\": \"0.93\"}}, {\"model\": \"markets.price\", \"pk\": 14, \"fields\": {\"price\": \"0.88\"}}, {\"model\": \"markets.price\", \"pk\": 15, \"fields\": {\"price\": \"0.87\"}}, {\"model\": \"markets.price\", \"pk\": 16, \"fields\": {\"price\": \"0.86\"}}, {\"model\": \"markets.price\", \"pk\": 17, \"fields\": {\"price\": \"0.85\"}}, {\"model\": \"markets.price\", \"pk\": 18, \"fields\": {\"price\": \"0.86\"}}, {\"model\": \"markets.price\", \"pk\": 19, \"fields\": {\"price\": \"0.87\"}}, {\"model\": \"markets.price\", \"pk\": 20, \"fields\": {\"price\": \"0.86\"}}, {\"model\": \"markets.price\", \"pk\": 26, \"fields\": {\"price\": \"0.87\"}}, {\"model\": \"markets.price\", \"pk\": 27, \"fields\": {\"price\": \"0.88\"}}, {\"model\": \"markets.price\", \"pk\": 28, \"fields\": {\"price\": \"0.87\"}}, {\"model\": \"markets.price\", \"pk\": 29, \"fields\": {\"price\": \"0.86\"}}, {\"model\": \"markets.price\", \"pk\": 30, \"fields\": {\"price\": \"0.85\"}}, {\"model\": \"markets.price\", \"pk\": 31, \"fields\": {\"price\": \"0.83\"}}, {\"model\": \"markets.price\", \"pk\": 32, \"fields\": {\"price\": \"0.85\"}}, {\"model\": \"markets.price\", \"pk\": 33, \"fields\": {\"price\": \"0.86\"}}, {\"model\": \"markets.price\", \"pk\": 34, \"fields\": {\"price\": \"0.85\"}}, {\"model\": \"markets.price\", \"pk\": 35, \"fields\": {\"price\": \"0.86\"}}, {\"model\": \"markets.price\", \"pk\": 36, \"fields\": {\"price\": \"0.87\"}}, {\"model\": \"markets.price\", \"pk\": 37, \"fields\": {\"price\": \"0.88\"}}, {\"model\": \"markets.price\", \"pk\": 38, \"fields\": {\"price\": \"0.89\"}}]"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can/should use serializers:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers


class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    labels = serializers.ListField(default=[1, 2, 3, 4])
    prices = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_prices(self, obj):
        return obj.prices.values_list('price', flat=True)


class ChartData(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Market.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []
    serializer_class = MySerializer
```

Comment: Thanks @yofee, that's really helpful. But is there a way to have this generate a simple list of prices, in the way it does with the (default) labels? That's what I need to send to the script generating the line chart (see added JQuery block above).

Comment: Ok, so what you need is something like `prices: [34.00, 53.99]`, correct?

Comment: yes, that's right @yofee - so it would send something like `{"labels": [1,2,3,4], "prices": [0.50,0.55,0.70,0.30]}` that I could then pick up as `data.labels` and `data.prices` in the JQuery block.

Comment: @kh_one please see my updated answer. This is probably the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the result because you are serializing the price_items twice. If you are using django serializers, then you should just use HttpResponse and return the data.

```
price_items = serializers.serialize('json', market.prices.get_queryset(), fields=('price'))
return HttpResponse(price_items,content_type='application/json')
```

If you want to return the labels also in the response, then I think this should work:

```
price_items = market.prices.get_queryset().values()   #include the fields you want to display in .values() as strings eg .values('prices')
labels = [1,2,3,4]
data = {
            "labels": labels,
            "prices": price_items}
return JsonResponse(data)
```

You might need to modify the `price_items` query according to your django model

Comment: Thanks, Ahmad! The HttpResponse solution gives me a properly formatted json tree, with each branch terminating in a 'price' field. So that's progress. But what I need to do is return a list of prices. Is there an easy way to generate such a list from the json I get from serialising?